# Throws IOException on Singleton Design Pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I am writing code which initially used static objects to hold data. I realized this was a code smell and have decided to implement the Singleton Design Pattern.

I have one object that throws an IOException and I am unable to initialize it when its being declared as a class variable. I have attached the code below.

Thank you

```
import java.import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataStorage{
  private static List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  private static List<Manager> managerList = new ArrayList <Manager>();
  private static List<Dish> allDishes = new ArrayList<Dish>();
  private static List<Table> allTables = new ArrayList<Table>();
  private static Inventory inventory = new Inventory(); //Error is given in this line

  private DataStorage () {}

  public static List<Employee> getEmpList() {
      return empList;
  }

  public static List<Manager> getManagerList() {
      return managerList;
  }

    public static List<Dish> getAllDishes() {
        return allDishes;
    }

  public static List<Table> getAllTables() {
      return allTables;
  }

  public static Inventory getInventory() {
      return inventory;
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you share the stack trace of the error, I'm not sure where you get the IOException

Comment: If IOException really throws out of this line it means `Inventory` class has an initialization problem either - default constructor or some static class variable or instance variable initialization or init static block performs some IO operation. Can it  be things like reading property file during initialization? look at Inventory class. I guess it is static variable initialization which happens during class loading...

Comment: Could you share the stack trace?

Comment: Are you getting "illegal modifier for inventory ; only final is permitted"?

Comment: Your implementation is not really singleton pattern alike. It's a class with static members only. Normally, you would create the one-and-only class instance on the first access. There you can catch exceptions, if required. Looking for 'java singleton pattern synchronized' may help. You may change your implemenation to make the DataStorage class a singleton with non-static members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One, your post does not contain a `Singleton` - a `Singleton` makes certain there is only a single instance of the class - and instead of having all of those `static` fields, they can be instance fields; because there is only one instance with a `Singleton`. Finally, since you mention that your `Inventory` constructor might throw `IOException` you could initialize that field lazily and wrap it with a try-catch. Like,

```
public final class DataStorage {
    private List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    private List<Manager> managerList = new ArrayList<Manager>();
    private List<Dish> allDishes = new ArrayList<Dish>();
    private List<Table> allTables = new ArrayList<Table>();
    private Inventory inventory = null;

    private static DataStorage _instance = new DataStorage();

    public static DataStorage getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    private DataStorage() {
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmpList() {
        return empList;
    }

    public List<Manager> getManagerList() {
        return managerList;
    }

    public List<Dish> getAllDishes() {
        return allDishes;
    }

    public List<Table> getAllTables() {
        return allTables;
    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        if (inventory == null) {
            try {
                inventory = new Inventory();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return inventory;
    }
}
```